# Copying same name files from different locations

Tags: powershell

For the purpose of incident response I am trying to create a powershell script that will go through all c:\users directories and copy the ntuser.dat then paste them into a new directory that the script creates. I have some pieces of the puzzle however I am having a hard time putting it all together. 
Some of the problems I cannot solve is 
1. Look for all c:\users*\ntuser.dat and unhide
2. Rename all ntuser.dat to include the folder name
3. Copying all newly renamed ntuser.dat into new folder
4. Renaming all ntuser.dat in c:\users back to normal.

```
#1 Unhides the ntuser.dat
$h = gci C:\Users\Test1\NTUSER.DAT -Force
$h.Attributes = $h.Attributes -bxor [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Hidden

#2 Renames ntuser.dat as foldername_ntuser.dat
Get-ChildItem C:\users\test1\ -Filter *.dat -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name+'_'+$_.Name}

#3 Creating a new folder and copying the newly named test_ntuser.dat 
$SourceFile = "c:\users\test1\*.dat"
$DestinationFile = "c:\users\user2\desktop\test\test_netuser.dat"
If (Test-Path $DestinationFile) {
    $i = 0
    While (Test-Path $DestinationFile) {
        $i +=1
        $DestinationFile = "c:\users\user2\desktop\test\"
    }
}Else {
    New-Item -ItemType file -Path $DestinationFile -Force
}
Copy-Item -Path $SourceFile -Destination $DestinationFile -Force
```

At the end of this I would like the script to unhide, rename, and move to a new folder from 
c:\users\test1\
c:\users\test2
c:\users\test3
Without having to reference each individual users path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you will have a few problems doing this as NTUSER.dat is loaded into memory if a user is being used. So you couldnt copy your own NTUSER.dat while you are logged into the computer. Also if there is a service running under the name of a user you will not be able to get those ether.

So lets go over what you wanted and why you didnt need it.

1 *Look for all c:\users*\ntuser.dat and unhide* : 
There is no need to unhide the original file. You just need to unhide the copy.

2 *Rename all ntuser.dat to include the folder name* : No Need to rename the original file just the copy.

3 *Copying all newly renamed ntuser.dat into new folder* : The Copy itself allows you to name the file whatever you want without the first 2 steps.

4 *Renaming all ntuser.dat in c:\users back to normal* : No need for this step ether as the original files were never renamed.

```
Function Copy-NTUser($SavePath){
    Get-ChildItem C:\Users\ -Directory | %{
        $Name = $_.Name
        Get-ChildItem "$($_.FullName)\ntuser.dat" -File -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | %{
            $FullName = $_.FullName
            try{
                Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "$($SavePath)\$($Name)_$($_.name)" -Force -PassThru  | %{
                    $_.Attributes = $_.Attributes -bxor [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Hidden
                }
            }catch{
                "$($FullName) could not be copied as its currently in use."
            }
        }
    }
}

Copy-NTUser -SavePath C:\Test\NTUSER
```